# ADL bug in VS2012?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2012

I suspect the following is a compiler bug but I'm looking for verification.  I've seen other SO questions that are similar to this but not an exact match.

Here's the code:

```
namespace my {
  // using std::swap;

  // Convenience utility
  template<typename T> void doSwap(T& l, T& r)
  {
    using namespace std;
    swap(l,r);
  }

  template<typename T> struct Container 
  {
    T t;
    void swap(Container<T>& r) { doSwap(this->t,r.t); }
  };

  // Specialize swap() for Container<T>
  template<typename T> void swap(Container<T>& l, Container<T>& r)
  { l.swap(r); }
}

void stuff()
{
  my::Container<int> one;
  my::Container<int> two;

  one.swap(two);
}
```

When I compile it with Visual Studio 2012, I get the following error:

```
error C2784: 'void my::swap(my::Container<T> &,my::Container<T> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'my::Container<T> &' from 'int'
see reference to function template instantiation 'void my::doSwap<T>(T &,T &)' being compiled
          with
          [
              T=int
          ]
```

If I uncomment the `using std::swap` at the top of the my namespace, it works.  Either way, the same code compiles under clang and g++ without so much as a warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this code is valid. But your `using namespace std;` should be `using std::swap;`. Currently in your code, it is as if an `std::swap` function had been declared at *global* scope (because that is the smallest enclosing scope that encloses both `std` and `my`. All declarations become visible at that scope for a `using namespace` directive). Had you moved the other `swap` overload before `doSwap`, it would fail for Clang and GCC aswell.

```
template<.....> void swap(....); // from namespace std

namespace my {
  // using std::swap;

  // Convenience utility
  template<typename T> void doSwap(T& l, T& r)
  {
    using namespace std;
    swap(l,r);
  }

  // ...
```

In the original code, on a Standards conforming compiler, this should lookup `swap` one time, and find `swap` at the global namespace. Then when instantiating it should look at the call again, and note that the call arguments are `int`, and there is no ADL possible with `int`. At instantiation time, normal lookup is not allowed to be done again, but only ADL. Therefore, the result will remain the global `swap` and things will work.

But MSVC appears to be doing the normal lookup for the call at instantiation time aswell (pobably because of its template parsing model. MSVC does not parse templates when they are defined, but only when they are instantiated with concrete types). Probably the then-visible `swap` overload within namespace `my` interferes and blocks the lookup from considering the global `swap`.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite grok the difference between "using std::swap" and "using namespace std" as it applies here but sure enough, it does make a difference.  Thanks!